# How to center h6 tag inside flex box

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can't center horizontally a h6 (or any) tag inside a flex div. I think I've tried all the CSS approaches align, justify, etc, but nothing works!

I just want to place a div with 80% of its size and put text inside it, is it supposed to be that hard?

[EDIT] Solved by adding `margin 0 auto` (do not forgot the `auto`) in the parent div css.

```css
div {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  align-self: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  width: 80%;
}

#n{border: 1px solid coral}
#y{border: 1px solid green}
h6{border: 1px solid blue}
```

```html
<div id="n">
  <h6>I won't align >:(</h6>
</div>
<br>
<div style="margin: 0 auto;" id="y">
  <h6>I do align :)</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty [center-aligned](https://jsfiddle.net/p2v8ot0a/1/) to me

Comment: You can try margin-right: auto; in h6 tag.

Comment: your h6 tag is fine. You just don't have your div center-aligned.

Comment: I meant vertically. I cant even distinguish between those anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check below snippet. I used border property of css & check where is **parent div** and child **h6**. After check, Your css code is working fine but if you want parent div should be in center also then you need to add **margin: 0 auto;** in **parent div**.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; width: 80%; border: 1px solid red;"><h6 style="border:1px solid blue;">h6 tag --- I am in center</h6></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because parent `div` container is not centered.

Set `margin: auto` for the parent div to place it center.

```html
<div style="margin: auto; display: flex; align-items: center; align-self: center; justify-content: center; justify-self: center; width: 80%;">
  <h6>I won't alignnnnnn</h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `div`:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; align-self: center; justify-content: center; justify-self: center; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h6>I am aligneeeeddd</h6>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/jOVNwmd